# time.thread_time() is missing from my miniconda3 installation (python3.7.1)

Tags: python, time, bioinformatics, attributeerror

I'm attempting to write some Python code using the `DigitalCellSorter` module (bio statistics-related). One of the methods in this module calls `time.thread_time()`, which I believe should be present in my Python installation since `thread_time()` was introduced in `Python 3.7` according to [this link to the time module description](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html). However, I cannot use `from time import thread_time`, and when I attempt to run my code I get this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'thread_time'
```

Do I need to re-install miniconda3? The only other clue I have is that that same link says that `thread_time()` is available on Unix systems that support `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` (I'm running Catalina on MacOS), but I can't find any information on whether my OS supports that or not.

EDIT: [image: Here's a picture of my code and error message.] The counts dataframe is a simple .csv with barcodes as columns, and genes as rows (as seen in the `expr_df.head()` output).

Comment: Try to start python3 from the conda environment you want to use and `import time` then have a look at the contents with `dir(time)` - is `thread_time` and `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` present in your env?

Comment: Running `dir(time)` shows that neither `thread_time` nor `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` are present in the current environment, which is the most recent version of Anaconda (I uninstalled, reinstalled, and updated everything this morning).

Comment: It looks like your macOS should support this according to: `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID should be available on macOS 10.12 and later (which is also when clock_gettime was introduced).`from https://bugs.python.org/issue32093. Could you double-check which python version you are using in your environment? Maybe with `conda list` and `which python` and add the output to your question.

Comment: Running `conda list` and `python --version` both show that I'm using Python 3.7.4, and `which python` shows me that I am in fact using `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python` (which I did a clean install and update of yesterday).

Comment: Can you add your code and the error stack trace to the question? I’ll try to reproduce the error on my machine

Comment: I edited my original post to include the original code and the error message. Unfortunately, as the data being used is proprietary I can't provide the data itself, but any dataframe should produce the same error.

Comment: Google results indicate that `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` is not available on Mac. You'll have to complain to the DigitalCellSorter people about their use of a Mac-incompatible function. (Judging by what we can see here, including stuff like `return print(...)`, DigitalCellSorter doesn't look like particularly well-written Python.)

Comment: Damn. Thanks for the assist though.